# Use UPDATE to populate column of 2nd table with AVG data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

Here are my two tables `sold_items` and `categories`. :

sold_items:

[image]

categories:

[image]

`sold_items` uses `id_Categories` from the `categories` table as a foreign key.

I'm using this command to try and populate the `average_price` of an item based in it's given "idCategories"- so either 1 or 2. 
I'm using this command to calculate the average price of items with an `idCategories` classification of `2`:

```
UPDATE categories SET average_price = (SELECT AVG(price) FROM sold_items) WHERE idCategories='2'
```

This command executes successfully with no errors, but rather than calculating the average price of the two items where idCategories = 2, it averages all of the products prices and inserts the value of `638.00` into the `categories` table so it looks liker this:

[image]

The value of the calculation done correctly would be 999.50 (i.e.1000+999/2). What is wrong with my SQL command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to specify where idCategories = 2, inside the sub query as well (SELECT AVG(price) FROM sold_items WHERE idCategories = 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE categories c
    SET average_price = (SELECT AVG(si.price)
                         FROM sold_items si
                         WHERE si.iDCategories = c.idCategories
                        )
    WHERE idCategories = 2;
```

This makes it much easier to update multiple categories at once -- or even all of them.

Note:  If your ids are numeric (which yours appear to be), don't use single quotes for comparisons.

Comment: Nice! I too was going to suggest this option as well.

Comment: HI Gordon, you mentioned I can update all categories at once, what would I change to do this? Cheers EDIT- also can you explain the `c` and `si` bit's? I've never seen those before

Comment: @bms9nmh . . . Those are table aliases.  They are generally recommends and very strongly recommended when a query refers to more than one table.  To update all categories, you would simply remove the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where idCategories = 2, inside the sub query as well:

```
UPDATE categories 
SET average_price = (SELECT AVG(price) FROM sold_items WHERE idCategories='2') 
WHERE idCategories=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE sold_items (
    idsold_items INT,
    item_number VARCHAR(7),
    title VARCHAR(14),
    URL VARCHAR(3),
    price INT,
    idCategories INT
)

CREATE TABLE categories (
    idCategories INT,
    model VARCHAR(7),
    averageprice FLOAT(10,2),
    keyword VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO sold_items
VALUES ('1', '14545', 'Equitek CAD', '...', '99', '1'),
       ('2', '454545', 'Equitek', '...', '454', '1'),
       ('3', '456645', 'Samsung', NULL, '999', '2'),
       ('4', '5456464', 'Samsung Galaxy', '', '1000', '2')

INSERT INTO categories
VALUES ('1', 'Equitek', NULL, ''),
       ('2', 'Samsung', NULL, NULL)

UPDATE categories
SET averageprice = CalculatedAverage.averagePrice
FROM categories
JOIN (
    SELECT
        idCategories,
        [averagePrice] = AVG(price)
    FROM sold_items
    GROUP BY idCategories
) CalculatedAverage ON categories.idCategories = CalculatedAverage.idCategories
```

Results:

```
idCategories     model    averageprice    keyword
1                Equitek  276.00
2                Samsung  999.00          NULL
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE exists in MySQL too. Can you tell me which bit of the syntax is incorrect?